# wget: unable to resolve host address

Tags: wget

I've RedHat Enterprise version 5.2.

I run this

```
wget --http-user=celee --http-password=1010$ -k -nd -np -r http://sp.kch.de/RandD/DesSup/Mask%20Tooling%20Runsets/ -o wget.log
```

The wget.log file give me error as:

```
--2014-10-22 09:02:19--  http://sp.kch.de/RandD/DesSup/Mask%20Tooling%20Runsets/
Resolving sp.kch.de... failed: No such file or directory.
wget: unable to resolve host address `sp.kch.de'
```

I have ping sp.kch.de it can reply me successful.
I run tracert sp.kch.de also successful.
Check the resolv.conf and nsswitch.conf

```
-rw-r--r-- 2 root root 42 Oct 17 16:18 resolv.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1715 Oct 10 09:14 nsswitch.conf
```

Run

```
$getent hosts sp.kch.de
192.168.1.2      sp.kch.de
```

I also manually add the sp.kch.de into HOST file.

Run by root user no problem, but no other user at this workstation.

Comment: Are you able to access files from other hosts using wget? Does it work if you try using the IP address in place of sp.kch.de in the URL?

Comment: I've found the solution, which is edit the /etc/nsswitch.conf and look for "hosts:" be sure it only like this "hosts: files nis dns" no other item.

Comment: I don't even get that error http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=EQ0ATnGN        though am running wget from windows there. ah it does say in a file wget.log that it creates-  Resolving sp.kch.de... 212.227.79.76
Connecting to sp.kch.de|212.227.79.76|:80...

Comment: Trying from debian usb, I see it makes wget.log and I get the error you mention. I see /etc/nsswitch.cong has `hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4`   I changed it to as you suggested, though wget still gave that error. I would restart but it's a USB. Anyhow, nice one for finding that solution that worked for you.. though I can't quite test the solution myself at the moment.